# Order of organization wide addresses in From dropdown box when sending email

Tags: email, case

When sending an email from a Case, the From dropdown shows all the verified organization wide email addresses.  But what is the order in which they are displayed?  It looks like from the screenshot below that it is alphabetical order based on the label, but there are some discrepancies.  Specifically, the 6 values starting at AMCS Wiley Support seem to be in the wrong place.

[image]

Comment: I am in the same boat. @hamayoun - did you get any solution of this?

Comment: Sorry Arun, there's no solution to this

Comment: any updates? from my experience we need to communicate with salesforce support team